# How to redirect someone after clicking on the menu

Tags: html, css, menu, web

I want to ask how to redirect someone after  clicking on something on my menu (Home, About, Contact, etc.) to the coresponding page.
I've been struggling with this for a while because I am not able to find any tutorial on the Internet, just started coding today and want to learn how to make a website.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to make a menu item (or many other page elements) clickable links is to wrap them in an html "anchor" tag. Suppose you have a menu item called "Visit the Home Page" that you want to take people to the page home.html when clicked. You could do that like this:

```
<a href="home.html">Visit the Home Page</a>
```

There's a lot more you can do with html, of course, but that should get you started. The web site Jon pointed you to in his comment, www.w3schools.com, is a wonderful resource for getting started with coding and writing web sites. You should definitely check it out.

--Eric

Comment: Thank you, but now I'm struggling with how to edit the home.html page.

Answer (score 0):

This is done with href attribute like the following code. Save it like index.html to see how it works

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="/about.html">About</a>

</html>
</body>
```

You will need to learn HTML, CSS, Javascript and a script language like PHP.
But if you want to build a website easily I suggest you to learn tools (CMS) like Wordpress or Drupal. There are a lot of pre-build websites with these CMS

Comment: Thank you, but now I'm struggling with how to edit the /about.html page.

Comment: about.html page can be edit the same way of index.html page. Just put both files in the same folder. You can get many templates from http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_templates.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can do that in the href attribute which takes the url you want to go to

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a href="home.html">Home</a>
        <a href="contact.html">Contact US</a>
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I'm struggling with how to edit the contact.html page.

Answer (score 0):

**In the Menu**

give id in `href="#home"`. See below code:

```
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#about">about</a>
<a href="#contact">contact</a>
```

**In the section**

```
<section id="home">Home page section</section>
<section id="about">about us section</section>
<section id="contact">contact us section</section>
```